Saving a pickle bytes object to an attribute in the Database issues an error
I am trying to persist a pickled predictive model into an attribute of an entity on the Database into the predictive_model_pickled attribute, declared as YAMS Bytes:
class Predictivemodel(EntityType):

    predictive_model_name = String(required=True, fulltextindexed=True,
                               maxsize=100, indexed=True,description=_('A name to identify the Predictive Model.'))

    predictive_model_statement = String(required=True, fulltextindexed=True,
                                    description=_('Declare a Predictive Model statement, so it can be more clearly understood.'))
    target_values_to_use_for_prediction = String(required=False, internationalizable=True,
                                             maxsize=100,
                                             description=_('The target values to use for the prediction.'),
                                             default=_('ACTUAL_VALUE'), vocabulary=['ACTUAL_VALUE','TARGET_VALUE'])
    predictive_measures_limit = Int(required=False,
                                    description=_('The maximun number of predictive Measures to include in the predictors.')
                                    , default=3)

    predictive_model = String(required=False,
                                description=_('The predictive model as JSON.'))

    predictive_model_pickled = Bytes(required=False,
                              description=_('The predictive model as Bytes.'))

This is the related code in the Hook __call__ :
def __call__(self):

    predictive_model_type = LinearRegression

    #(some more code to create the LinearRegression predictive model, which is fitted and predicts just fine.)

    serialized_predictive_model = pickle.dumps(predictive_model)
    entity.cw_edited['predictive_model_pickled'] = serialized_predictive_model

It issues the on-web-page error:
predictive_model_pickled-subject : incorrect value (b'\x80\x04\x95\xb2\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x1asklearn.linear_model._base\x94\x8c\x10LinearRegression\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\rfit_intercept\x94\x88\x8c\x06copy_X\x94\x88\x8c\x06n_jobs\x94N\x8c\x08positive\x94\x89\x8c\x0en_features_in_\x94K\x02\x8c\x05coef_\x94\x8c\x15numpy.core.multiarray\x94\x8c\x0c_reconstruct\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94K\x00\x85\x94C\x01b\x94\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01K\x02\x86\x94h\x0e\x8c\x05dtype\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x02f8\x94\x89\x88\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01<\x94NNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00t\x94b\x89C\x10|*\xa5l\x83\x0e\xe1?\xfcj-\xb3\x18l\xf7\xbf\x94t\x94b\x8c\x05rank_\x94K\x02\x8c\tsingular_\x94h\rh\x10K\x00\x85\x94h\x12\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x02\x85\x94h\x1a\x89C\x10\xfa_$\nH\xace@\xbeDW\x19\xa5"^@\x94t\x94b\x8c\nintercept_\x94h\rh\x10K\x00\x85\x94h\x12\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01\x85\x94h\x1a\x89C\x08\xf2\xfdyJ3\xa0b@\x94t\x94b\x8c\x10_sklearn_version\x94\x8c\x051.3.2\x94ub.') for type "Bytes"

I kindly ask the question in two possible ways to solve this:
Possible solution 1) How can I persist a bytes object/variable created by pickle into a Bytes attribute of a Cubicweb Entity type?
Possible solution 2) Is there any other way I can persist the predictive model into the attribute of a Cubicweb Entity type in a way that I can later retrieve it and get the predictive model back in a view? I need t show its parameters and make additional predictions in the view.
I know the serialized_predictive_model is a bytes python object:
(Pdb) type(serialized_predictive_model)
<class 'bytes'>

And if I un-pickle the serialized predictive model, it works fine too:
predictive_model = pickle.loads(serialized_predictive_model)
predictive_model
LinearRegression()

vars(predictive_model)
{'fit_intercept': True, 'copy_X': True, 'n_jobs': None, 'positive': False, 'n_features_in_': 2, 'coef_': array([[ 0.53302165, -1.46389074]]), 'rank_': 2, 'singular_': array([173.3837939 , 120.54132684]), 'intercept_': array([149.0062611])}

So I do not understand why it issues an error when trying to persist it to a Cubicweb Bytes attribute. Please let me know if I'm missing something and how to fix it.
